# React Hook Form I have a file type & type checkbox next to each other, when onClick a checkbox type is opening a modal and asking for a file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, event-listener, react-hook-form

It is like the event listener ***SPILLS OVER*** to the adjacent type!
I have a react hook for with a checkbox and a type text next to each other. Both text and checkboxes were working fine. Now I changed the type text to type file , so that I can upload files and take only the names of the files. But after this change when clicking the checkbox , it is behaving as a type file, meaning when clicking the checkbox , a modal opens up and asks for a file type to be uploaded. If I change the type of file to type text , then the checkbox behaves as checkbox. Is it some kind of a bug in react hook form or have I done something wrong?

```
   <TableCell className="border">
                  <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name={`PSSE_File.${index}.path_to_dll_folder` as const}
                    render={({ field: { value, onChange, ...field } }) => {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <input
                            type="file"
                            {...field}
                            // value={"hello"}
                            onChange={(event) => {
                              onChange(
                                event.target.files && event.target.files[0].name
                              )
                            }}
                            // className=" border rounded outline-none "
                            className="opacity-0 absolute"
                            disabled={
                              PSSE_File_Info_Is_Submitted ||
                              methods.formState.isSubmitting
                            }
                          />
                          {/* <p>{JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}</p> */}
                          <div className="w-32  truncate">
                            {value ? (
                              <div className=" border rounded outline-none px-2 py-2">
                                {value}
                              </div>
                            ) : (
                              <div className="flex items-center justify-center space-x-2 w-full cursor-pointer border rounded outline-none h-10">
                                <div className="">
                                  <icons.AiOutlineCloudUpload />
                                </div>
                                <h2>Upload</h2>
                              </div>
                            )}
                          </div>
                        </>
                      )
                    }}
                  />

                  <div className="h-12">
                    {methods.formState.errors?.PSSE_File &&
                      methods.formState.errors?.PSSE_File[index]
                        ?.path_to_dll_folder?.message && (
                        <span className="text-xs text-red-600">
                          {
                            methods.formState.errors?.PSSE_File[index]
                              ?.path_to_dll_folder?.message
                          }
                        </span>
                      )}
                  </div>
                </TableCell>

                <TableCell className="border">
                  <div className="text-center">
                    <Controller
                      name={`PSSE_File.${index}.case_selection`}
                      control={methods.control}
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <input
                          className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600"
                          type="checkbox"
                          {...field}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            e.stopPropagation()
                            field.onChange(Number(e.target.checked))
                          }}
                          checked={field.value === 1}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="h-12"></div>
                </TableCell>
                {index == 0 && (
                  <TableCell className=" flex justify-center ">
                    <div className=" text-slate-400 text-center bg-white  focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-lg px-2 py-2 mr-2 mt-1 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800 cursor-not-allowed ">
                      <icons.RiDeleteBin5Line />
                    </div>
                    {/* <div className="h-4 w-4"></div> */}
                  </TableCell>
                )}
                {index > 0 && (
                  <TableCell className=" flex justify-center ">
                    {!PSSE_File_Info_Is_Submitted && (
                      <div
                        onClick={() => {
                          remove(index)
                        }}
                        className=" cursor-pointer text-red-500 text-center  disabled:bg-slate-300  bg-white hover:bg-slate-200 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-lg px-2 py-2 mr-2 mt-1 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
                      >
                        <icons.RiDeleteBin5Line />
                      </div>
                    )}
                    {PSSE_File_Info_Is_Submitted && (
                      <div className=" cursor-not-allowed text-slate-400 text-center  disabled:bg-slate-300  bg-white focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-lg px-2 py-2 mr-2 mt-1 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                        <icons.RiDeleteBin5Line />
                      </div>
                    )}
                    {/* <div className="h-4 w-4"></div> */}
                  </TableCell>
                )}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
```

I did try to changing back to file type to text type and everything was working normal.

Comment: My assumption is that adding a z-index CSS to a higher no. will make the check box work correctly next not input type file

Comment: @Lokesh  , Thankyou for you response. I did try your solution , but it didnt work as a solution.  The Only work around is to change the position of the checkbox from being next to the type file and place it next to a type text, but it is against the design in place.